# SOP POS of MIPS OR function

Tags: mips

I am a beginner to MIPS studying comp. architecture. The problem, I am stuck at is.
I was asked by my teacher to prepare a  SOP and POS for OR instruction in MIPS. ORing 2 registers. I am confused that how to do so. Should I make a k-map??  If so.. then again stuck.. when considering variables.. Should I consider 32 variables in k-map? or just 2 (A and B)?? Can any one help.
P.S. This is just my first question to stack.. Otherwise I was getting ans to all questions in search.
Thank you
I have tried searching it on Google and over where as well. Unfortunately it did not answer my question

Comment: What are SOP and POS?

Comment: Sop is sum of products. Pos is product of sums. Which we make from truth table. Giving ourselves ease in reading the circuit.. still the question  remains. That how to make a truth table for two 32 bit registers ORing in mips?

Comment: Are you supposed to decode an instruction word as an OR instruction, or implement an OR instruction by or-ing two registers together?

Comment: I am sorry for late reply but I just got the answer. I am new here so did not visited the account regularly. This time I have another problem. Stuck since one complete day. Can you help here? Kindly. Thanks  http://stackoverflow.com/q/27211494/4214165