# No response to update query in oracle

Tags: php, html, oracle

I am a beginner . I made a php html combined page(viewemployees.php) to display my table from oracle data base. It worked fine. Then i  made a page to edit  my data base table(editemployees.php).  that page has two functions.  It displays the original table and a simple form which should contain the elements to update the table. When we place values in the form it directs us to  a new php page(een.php) where it updates table and returns back to editemployees.php showing the updated table. but i am stuck when i fill in the form  AND NOTHING happens.  Even I have placed a condition that to echo a line if new value field is null. still that line is not echoed. This is some weird thing. I am posting both of my edit and view pages code click the link. kindly help. 
 In simple my table update is not working and showing  undefined variable error at line 4 of een.php. Why is taht variabl undefined?? can anyone help please

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xtuvotdy7c9wr1v/AADrNSlC_EJ0YkyDDkhe8mKGa?dl=0

```html
<?php

include("connection.php");
$empid = $_POST['EMPLOYEE ID'];
$field = $_POST['EDIT FIELD'];
$nfield     = $_POST['NEW VALUE'];

echo $field;
if( empty($_POST['NEW VALUE'] )){
echo "type new field properly";
 }
else 
{
$e = filter_var($empid, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$f = filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$nf = filter_var($nfield, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
}

if( $e==$empid && $f==$field && $nf==$nfield)
{
if ($field=="age" || $field=="sal"){
$sel = "seleect * from employ";
$st = oci_parse(conn, $sel);
oci_execute($st);
$query = " update employ  set $field = $nfield where empid = $empid";
$stmt = oci_parse($conn,$query);
oci_execute($stmt, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
oci_free_statement($updateTitleInserted); 
oci_close($conn);
echo oci_error();
header("Location: home.html");
}

else{

$query = "update employ set $field = '$nfield' where empid = $empid";
$stmt = oci_parse($conn,$query);
oci_execute($stmt,OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
oci_free_statement($updateTitleInserted); 
oci_close($conn);
echo oci_error();
echo $field;

}
}


else 
echo "wrong data entry go back and enter again";

?>
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question. Never use dropbox here.

Comment: Also certainly the code you uploaded is not the same that gives you that error.

Comment: here it is. on line 4. where I have declared $empisd says undefined index.   and it continues then with errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line does not make sense.

```
$empid = $_POST["EMPLOYER ID"];
```

A post variable name cannot contain a space.